# trying to control mouse with nunchuck using glove pie script

Tags: scripting, wiimote

I have been trying to control my nunchuck using glove pie and I want to use it as a mouse. Now my main problem is with the 2 nunchuck buttons the C and Z buttons, what I want to happen is:
the z button would be left click
the c button would be right click
yet the code I used seemed to make whenever I press the Z or C button on the nunchuck it does both right click and left click at the same time despite that not being in the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didnt include any code I can't know your exact problem. I would recommend you try using this:

```
Mouse.LeftButton = Wiimote.Nunchuk.CButton
Mouse.RightButton = Wiimote.Nunchuk.ZButton
```